# PyGame: Panning tiled map causes gaps

Tags: python, pygame, tile

I'm using PyGame 1.9.2 on Python 3.4.3 (Win8.1).

My game window consists of a tiled map using 48x48px tiles. The game's framework moves the tiles according to player input using the following method of the game's framwork class:

```
def moveTiles(self):
    xmove = self.parent.dt * self.panning[0] * self.panning_speed
    ymove = self.parent.dt * self.panning[1] * self.panning_speed
    for tile in self.game_map:
        tile.x += xmove
        tile.y += ymove
        tile.rect.x = int(tile.x)
        tile.rect.y = int(tile.y)
        tile.pos = (tile.rect.x, tile.rect.y)
```

While "self.panning_speed" is pretty self-explanatory, self.panning is a list containing two values for x and y panning (e.g. [0, 0] = no panning, [-1, 1] = panning down-left, etc.).

The tile.x/tile.y values are then "int'ed" to be used as x-/y-values of the rect and the pos (the latter used for blitting).

I add the exact same amount to every single tile's x/y value, then I use "int" on them which, to my knowledge, always floors the float down to the next lower int. So technically seen the relative change to every single tile's x/y value is the exactly same as to any other tile's x/y value.

Yet: I still get gaps between rows or columns from time to time! Those gaps appear irregularly but are very visible and when you stop panning while a gap is visible that gap will stay until you pan again.

See this image for an example:
[See this image for an example (black line in the red square is the gap; gold and pink are the tiles)](https://ibb.co/kuTAgb)

Where in my code can these gaps occur?

Comment: `float` number can't keep every value so we have situation that `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`.

Comment: I would use only integer values. Or [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html). Or integer values and in one variable  keep difference between int and float to cumulate this difference and later add to all variables 1 when it cumulate value bigger then 1.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then it'll be a lot easier for us to give you a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work better. Just add the `velocity` to the `panning` vector when the player is moving and never move the tiles. The panning is then added to the `rect.topleft` position of the tiles when they're blitted to get the correct position. You have to convert the panning to integers first (create another vector, called `offset` in the example) before you add it to the tile positions or you'll still get gaps.

```
import itertools
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


TILE_SIZE = 44
TILE_IMG1 = pg.Surface((TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
TILE_IMG1.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue3'))
TILE_IMG2 = pg.Surface((TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
TILE_IMG2.fill(pg.Color('aquamarine3'))


class Tile(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    dt = 0

    image_cycle = itertools.cycle((TILE_IMG1, TILE_IMG2))
    game_map = pg.sprite.Group()
    # Create tile instances and add them to the game map group.
    for y in range(16):
        for x in range(20):
            image = next(image_cycle)
            game_map.add(Tile((x*TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE), image))
        next(image_cycle)

    panning = Vector2(0, 0)
    velocity = Vector2(0, 0)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_a:
                    velocity.x = 100
                elif event.key == pg.K_d:
                    velocity.x = -100
            elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_d and velocity.x < 0:
                    velocity.x = 0
                elif event.key == pg.K_a and velocity.x > 0:
                    velocity.x = 0

        # Add the velocity to the panning when we're moving.
        if velocity.x != 0 or velocity.y != 0:
            panning += velocity * dt

        game_map.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        # Assigning screen.blit to a local variable improves the performance.
        screen_blit = screen.blit
        # Convert the panning to ints.
        offset = Vector2([int(i) for i in panning])
        # Blit the tiles.
        for tile in game_map:
            # Add the offset to the tile's rect.topleft coordinates.
            screen_blit(tile.image, tile.rect.topleft+offset)

        pg.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(30) / 1000


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Another alternative would be to blit the tiles onto a big background surface at program start. Then you won't get gaps and that also improves the performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The issue with blitting all on one big background is that the tiles are animated. If I understand PyGame correctly, I'd have to "double blit", i.e. I'd blit the tile on the surface and then the surface on the screen. Wouldn't that actually be more consuming or do I misunderstand something here? I will, by the way, use a "camera" approach now. Like this I move the camera and not the tile, only blit them relative to the camera.

Comment: With animated tiles you probably can't use the solution with the background image. How exactly do you animate the tiles?

Comment: I've edited the answer, because there were still gaps. You need to convert the `panning` (which is a pretty basic camera btw) to integers before you add it to the tile positions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts! My camera approach is actually very similar to what you show here. I make this the accepted answer though the others also gave me important insights. One detail I noticed in your code: you use an fps cap and dt? Is this a better approach than only using dt?

Comment: If you don't call [`clock.tick`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) the game will run with the maximum frame rate that your computer can achieve, so it should usually be called once per frame. Since it also returns the delta time, we can just use it instead of calculating it ourselves. BTW, if you multiply the velocity by the `dt` then you have a "variable time step" and that's not good for online multiplayer games (I think it's okay for single player games). Here's an interesting link: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html

Comment: Thanks again! I'm currently not yet looking into MP gaming but might do so in the future, so your link is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is that `float` can't keep every value and we have situation that  `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` And it can makes difference between expected result and obtained result.

You can use only integer values to change position for all tiles ie.

```
tile.rect.x = int(xmove)
tile.rect.y = int(ymove)
```

This way you can loose only small value (smaller then one pixel) but if you cumulate many small values then you can get few pixels.

So you can try to cumulate differences between float and integer values.

I can't check if this works correctly but I would do something like this

```
def moveTiles(self):

    # add moves to already cumulated differences betweeen floats and integers
    self.xcululated += self.parent.dt * self.panning[0] * self.panning_speed
    self.ycululated += self.parent.dt * self.panning[1] * self.panning_speed

    # get only integer values
    xmove = int(self.xcululated)
    ymove = int(self.ycululated)

    # remove integers from floats
    self.xcululated += xmove
    self.ycululated += ymove

    for tile in self.game_map:
        # use the same integer values for all tiles
        tile.rect.x += xmove
        tile.rect.y += tmove
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I decided to go by a camera approach. Instead of moving the tiles I blit them relative to the camera position. Like this I don't have gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main problem is that your game assets do not have *padding*.

Padding is extremely important to have in your assets especially when you are using cameras and float values.

Sometimes when using a camera the float value does not provide the accuracy that is needed and can cause *texture bleeding* or the lines that you see from time to time in your game.

The solution is to add padding to your assets.

The way I do this is as follows:

1. Download and install GIMP
2. Install a plugin that can add padding from [here](http://registry.gimp.org/node/26044).
3. Load every asset and add padding using the plugin in GIMP.

There is no need to change the name of any of the assets. Just add the padding and overwrite.

I hope this helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the issue by using a simple camera to move the map. That works perfectly so far. However, giving padding to my tiles was another idea I pursued for a while. I'll have a look into it too.

Comment: Yes, adding padding will allow for more complex movement of the camera if needed in future, Be sure to consider it in the future!

Comment: Thank you, I shall have a look into it!