# All the sprites have to move in pygame

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

I am using Vector2 for my game to make the camera. But when I collided with the wall all the sprites started moving so I fixed it with my walls and floor, but I can't figure out how to fix my enemy. Any ideas?

this is my code:

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2

width = 1280
height = 720
x1 = 200
y1 = 100
x2 = 500
y2 = 400
x3 = 100
y3 = 300
x = 0
y = 0

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load("character.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

#enemy class
class Enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, waypoints, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.image.load("enemy.png")
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(self.image, (int(50), int(50)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(0,0)
        self.max_speed = 5
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)
        self.waypoints = waypoints
        self.waypoint_index = 0
        self.target = self.waypoints[self.waypoint_index]
        self.target_radius = 50
        self.rect.x = width / 2
        self.rect.y = height / 2

    def update(self):
# A vector pointing from self to the target.
        heading = self.target - self.pos
        distance = heading.length()  # Distance to the target.
        heading.normalize_ip()
        if distance <= 2:  # We're closer than 2 pixels.
          # Increment the waypoint index to swtich the target.
          # The modulo sets the index back to 0 if it's equal to the length.
          self.waypoint_index = (self.waypoint_index + 1) % len(self.waypoints)
          self.target = self.waypoints[self.waypoint_index]
        if distance <= self.target_radius:
                # If we're approaching the target, we slow down.
          self.vel = heading
        else:  # Otherwise move with max_speed.
          self.vel = heading * self.max_speed

        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

#Enemy waypoints
waypoints = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]]


class Floor(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.image.load("floor.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class SideWall(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.image.load("sidewall.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class TopAndBottomWall(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.image.load("topandbottomwall.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    #all the sprites group
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()

    #the floor
    floor = Floor(540, -620, all_sprites)

    #player
    player = Player(((width / 2), (height / 2)), all_sprites)

    #walls group
    walls = pg.sprite.Group()

    #all walls
    walltop = TopAndBottomWall(540, -620, all_sprites, walls)
    wallbottom = TopAndBottomWall(540, 410, all_sprites, walls)
    wallleft = SideWall((width / 2) - 100, (height / 2) - 930, all_sprites, walls)
    wallright = SideWall((wallleft.rect.x + (1920 - 50)), (height / 2) - 930, all_sprites, walls)

    #all enemy's
    enemy = Enemy((100, 300), waypoints, all_sprites)

    camera = Vector2(0, 0)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            #player movement    
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    player.vel.x = 5
                elif event.key == pg.K_a:
                    player.vel.x = -5
                elif event.key == pg.K_w:
                    player.vel.y = -5
                elif event.key == pg.K_s:
                    player.vel.y = 5
            elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_d and player.vel.x > 0:
                    player.vel.x = 0
                elif event.key == pg.K_a and player.vel.x < 0:
                    player.vel.x = 0
                elif event.key == pg.K_w:
                    player.vel.y = 0
                elif event.key == pg.K_s:
                    player.vel.y = 0

        camera -= player.vel

        all_sprites.update()

        if pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, walls, False):
            #stop the left wall from moving
            wallleft.rect.x = wallleft.rect.x + player.vel.x
            wallleft.rect.y = wallleft.rect.y + player.vel.y
            #stop the top wall from moving
            walltop.rect.y = walltop.rect.y + player.vel.y
            walltop.rect.x = walltop.rect.x + player.vel.x
            #stop the right wall from moving
            wallright.rect.x = wallright.rect.x + player.vel.x
            wallright.rect.y = wallright.rect.y + player.vel.y
            #stop the bottom wall from moving
            wallbottom.rect.x = wallbottom.rect.x + player.vel.x
            wallbottom.rect.y = wallbottom.rect.y + player.vel.y
            #stop the floor from moving
            floor.rect.x = floor.rect.x + player.vel.x
            floor.rect.y = floor.rect.y + player.vel.y


        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        for sprite in all_sprites:
            screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft+camera)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

main()
pg.quit()
```

This is a link with the files if you want to run it.
https://geordyd.stackstorage.com/s/hZZ1RWcjal6ecZM

Answer (score 1):

You are working with *screen coordinates*. You only move the walls while checking for keypresses; you should move the enemies at the same time.

But there is a far better way; more expandable if you add more classes, and less confusing.

Remove the keypresses check out of `Wall` and put them into `Player`. This will change the player's position in *world coordinates*, the same coordinates as the walls are (static) and the enemies move in (dynamic).

Then draw both walls and enemies at `world_position - players_position`, adjusted for the player's relative position in the center. Technically even the player itself is drawn at that position – the calculation for him amounts to zero movement *relative to the screen*.

For even more flexibility you could consider a separate `Camera` class, which is set up to follow the player by default. That allows you to let the camera move 'elsewhere', or if the player is near the edge of your world, let him walk off the screen center.

Comment: I tried adding a camera class before, but I couldn't figure out how so I thought this was a little bit easier. So do you have any tips on how to add the camera?

Comment: @Geordyd: a camera class is not really required, it only enables you to do some more display tricks. Fix your current code first to work correctly, then you can think about enhancements.

Comment: @Geordyd take a look at this [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036774/6220679) that I've posted recently. When the player moves, I just change the `panning` vector and then add it to the tile positions during the rendering to offset them.